# Add Index Key on Field

Tags: sql

I used the following to add FULLTEXT and INDEX on my table fields like this:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX searchindex ON Entries(title, tags, entry);
```

But I added another field (keywords) in the table that I also need to add FULLTEXT and INDEX on.  I added FULLTEXT but I didn't add the INDEX so now I am getting error: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list.

I tried adding the INDEX after the fact and this is what I used with no luck:

```
ALTER TABLE Entries ADD INDEX searchindex(keywords);
```

Giving the error: #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'keywords' used in key specification without a key length

Any help is appreciated.  Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: What is the data type of `keywords`? And besides: shouldn't you drop the existing index and create a new one, comprising of all 4 columns now?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge, you can only have only FT index on a table...

Comment: Thanks Koen.  I didn't think to drop the index and then redo it.  That fixed my problem.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can not define index by TEXT / BLOB columns without specifying index length:

#### BLOB and TEXT columns also can be indexed, but a prefix length must be given.

Logically - that is because these data types represent huge data and, therefore, index can not be created by whole field.

So I think should alter keyword column by specifying length of column like text(50).

Answer (score 0):

I had to Drop the INDEX then recreate the INDEX for all the required fields.

```
ALTER TABLE Entries DROP INDEX searchindex;
```